# Find object in NSOrderedSet in CoreData. index(ofAccessibilityElement :)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsorderedset

I have an ordered To Many relationship and Xcode 8 has generated an attribute of type NSOrderedSet with a bunch of helper functions to insert and remove elements.

Now I am trying to find an object and the Apple documentation indicates that the following function is available for NSOrderedSet:

```
func index(of object: Any) -> Int
```

However when I want to use this function the compiler and the autocompletion want me to use the following function instead:

```
func index(ofAccessibilityElement element: Any) -> Int
```

which doesn't seem to be finding anything.

Could someone please help me understand what is going on?

Comment: According to the docs, it's `func index(of: Any)`, not `of object: Any`.

Comment: The function is referenced here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsorderedset/1411856-index)

Comment: I am just wondering if I am the only one getting this error, or if it's a bug, or me doing something wrong.

Comment: This is really odd.  That contradicts what is shown here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsorderedset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocompletion can and often is wrong. It can be handy but it's not a reference for what's correct.

I don't know what you mean about the compiler wanting to use that method, because it's not what you need to look up objects in an ordered set. The correct method would be `index(of:)`, as in

```
var myset = NSMutableOrderedSet(array: [1, 2, 3])

myset.index(of:2)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, I think I was a bit tired and I was calling index(of:) on my entity instead of my attribute... Your answer helped me reviewing my issue.